# How to make a bootstrap date picker to have the certain dates selected

Tags: angularjs, uidatepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap datepicker in my code. Problem with my requirement is that I want to have certain dates to be selected in the datepicker on which deliveries will be made. I am new to angular JS and have no Idea how to do that. Can someone help me in this ?

PS:I do not require the calendar to take input It is just needed to show the selected dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `custom-class` attribute to do this.

From the documentation

> custom-class (date, mode) (Default: null) : An optional expression to
>   add classes based on passing date and current mode (day|month|year).

Here is a sample of the relevant handler adapted from the Angular UI Bootstrap example

```
...
$scope.events =
    [
      {
        date: new Date(2015, 9, 1),
        status: 'delivered'
      },
      {
        date: new Date(2015, 9, 5),
        status: 'delivered'
      },
      {
        date: new Date(2015, 9, 15),
        status: 'delivered'
      }
    ];

$scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i=0;i<$scope.events.length;i++){
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
...
```

---

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/vJl8hDUfsBOJsLXFNKWQ?p=preview